# Black box testing in java null value tests

Tags: java, black-box-testing

If I had the following code

```
public static <T> int count(List<T> list, T elem) {
  int count = 0; // the result
  for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if (list.get(i).equals(elem))
  count++;
  }
 return count;
}
```

Lets say I need to run a black box test,

Like so,

Input

`[null], null      Output should be 0`

Firstly, is this a worthwhile test case? ( for black box testing)

If not,

Then I ask, are null values worth while tests for black box testing in any case?(in general)

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, your method could be replaced by `int count = Collections.frequency(list, elem);`...

Comment: @assylias has an ensure result >=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How code reacts to null inputs is something that should be documented and tested, yes.

Comment: It doesn't hurt.  And, it documents for the reader that `null` is permissible as an argument.   Why not use a foreach loop though?

Comment: Alright great, was kind of unsure as to whether they were worthwhile or not

Comment: +1 for "use a foreach loop". If that is a non-random-access list, then access by index might be quite slow.

Comment: Oh that isn't my code it was just the example in a text book, I was more wondering the best way to structure black box tests... But I can see how a for each would be more appropriate